# fputcsv не может отформатировать строку

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая отлично записывает данные в файл и сохраняет его на "лету". Вот только проблема в том, что когда пытаюсь отформатировать данные для `resultArray`, через fputcsv, он не может этого сделать и возвращает:

> Веб-страница по адресу ***, возможно, временно недоступна или
> постоянно перемещена по новому адресу

Однако для более простого массива `selectedColumn` всё получается. Ниже приведены код и `resultArray`. Не могу понять почему так происходит. Может массив не верно составлен и не может из-за этого отформатироваться?

Код:

```
function checkEmptyField($field)
{
  if(empty($field))
  {
    return '-';
  }else
  {
    return $field;
  }
}

$nameFile = 'keywords.csv';
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
        
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$nameFile);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        
// Create head of table
$selectedColumn = [];
foreach ($clientColumns as $key=>$val)
{
  if($val == 1)
  {
     $selectedColumn [] = $key;
  }
}
      
// Create body of table
$resultArray = [$selectedColumn];
foreach ($keywordsCharacteristic as $fields) 
{
   $tempRow = [];
   foreach ($selectedColumn as $column)
   {
      switch ($column) {
        case "features":
          $tempRow [] = $fields['serpFeatures'];
          break;
        case "position":
          $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['position']);
          break;
        case "traffic":
          $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['traffic']);
          break;
        case "volume":
          $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['volume']);
          break;
        case "CPC":
          $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['cpc']);
          break;
        case "url":
            $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['pageUrl']);
            break;
        case "checked":
          $tempRow [] = checkEmptyField($fields['checked']);
          break;
        }
      }
      $resultArray [] = $tempRow;
}
var_dump($resultArray);
//fputcsv($handle, $resultArray);
fclose($handle);
exit();
```

По поводу `resultArray`. Даже если я уберу поля, соответствующие `features`, то результата также не будет, хотя массив станет таким же, как в примере из [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fputcsv.php), только крупнее.

> Поле, соответствующие `features`:

> ```
> [0]=>
>     array(2) {
>       [0]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["key"]=>
>         string(7) "reviews"
>         ["img"]=>
>         string(11) "reviews.png"
>         ["name"]=>
>         string(7) "Reviews"
>       }
>       [1]=>
>       array(3) {
>         ["key"]=>
>         string(15) "relatedSearches"
>         ["img"]=>
>         string(12) "Searches.png"
>         ["name"]=>
>         string(16) "Related Searches"
>       }
>     }
> ```

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "features"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "position"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "traffic"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "volume"
    [4]=>
    string(3) "CPC"
    [5]=>
    string(3) "url"
    [6]=>
    string(7) "checked"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(7) "reviews"
        ["img"]=>
        string(11) "reviews.png"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Reviews"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(15) "relatedSearches"
        ["img"]=>
        string(12) "Searches.png"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Related Searches"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "2022-02-07"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(7) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(7) "reviews"
        ["img"]=>
        string(11) "reviews.png"
        ["name"]=>
        string(7) "Reviews"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(5) "tweet"
        ["img"]=>
        string(9) "tweet.png"
        ["name"]=>
        string(5) "Tweet"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(3) {
        ["key"]=>
        string(15) "relatedSearches"
        ["img"]=>
        string(46) "Searches.png"
        ["name"]=>
        string(16) "Related Searches"
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    string(1) "3"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "-"
    [6]=>
    string(10) "2022-02-07"
  }
}
```

Comment: Можете тестировать на то что возвращает вызов fputcsv на false и проверять через [error_get_last](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-get-last.php). Есть также вероятность что у вас возникает ошибка из-за ассоциативных ключей у массивов - попробуйте их удалить.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Можете более подробно описать как это проверить? Из-за ассоциативных ключей? Да вроде нет. Они только для поля `features`, а я его тоже удалял из массива безрезультатно

Comment: В смысле как проверить? Вызываете $result = fputcsv($handle, $resultArray); if ($result === false) { var_dump(error_get_last(); die; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решено**
Причиной было то, что я не пропускал `resultArray` через foreach и у меня передавался массив как элемент, вместо поэлементной записи. Проблему с `features` решил через array_merge. Результирующий код выглядит так:

```
$nameFile = 'keywords.csv';
$handle = fopen("php://output", "w");
        
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$nameFile);
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=UTF-8');
        
// Create head of table
$selectedColumn = ['keyword'];
foreach ($clientColumns as $key=>$val)
{
    if($val == 1)
    {
        $selectedColumn [] = $key;
    }
}

// Create body of table
$resultArray = [$selectedColumn];
foreach ($keywordsCharacteristic as $fields) 
{
    $tempRow = ["\"".$fields['keyword']."\""];
    foreach ($selectedColumn as $column)
    {
       switch ($column) {
            /* Код из вопроса тут не менялся */
        }
    }
    $resultArray [] = $tempRow;
}
foreach ($resultArray as $key=>$item){
    $stringFeatures = '';
    if(is_array($item[1])){
        foreach ($item[1] as $serpFeatures){
            if($serpFeatures['key'] == end($item[1])['key']){
                $stringFeatures .= $serpFeatures['key'];
            }else{
                $stringFeatures .= $serpFeatures['key'].", ";
            }                    
        }
        unset($item[1]);
        $res = array_merge(array_slice($item, 0, 1, true),
            array(1 => "\"$stringFeatures\""),
            array_slice($item, 1, count($item), true) );
        unset($stringFeatures);
        fputcsv($handle, $res, ";", '"');
    }else{
        fputcsv($handle, $item, ";", '"');
    }
}
fclose($handle);
exit();
```